# how to reverse the curtain scroll effect multiple times on a single page layout

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to recreate this effect but the opposite directions and layers opposite as well.

So at the end of this example the final page scrolls up revealing a fixed form...

I want the effect to be in reverse, so the first page is fixed and the 2nd  page scrolls up covering it. then when the 2nd page covers the whole page it becomes fixed and the form would then scroll up covering the second page.

Can not figure this out someone please help or shoot me in the right direction.

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kppn6/39/

Also I would like to recreate this effect with `%` or `em` tags so the pages will be `100%` of the viewport and once they scroll up covering `100%` of the original page they become fixed.

Is this possible? If so how?